# How to refer to roles and users in Entity Framework Model Designer inside MVC 5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, schema, roles

How to refer to roles and users in Entity Framework Model Designer inside MVC 5 project?
I would like to connect `Note` entity with UserProfile or Role.

How to achieve refering to `UserProfile` in schema designer? In EF model first approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean UserProfile and Role from Asp.Net membership classes?
What I usually do: after first usage of the Asp.Net membership the corresponding tables will be created in DB. Then I simply add those tables to the schema designer and it will create corresponding classes.

Comment: In `IdentityModels.cs` there is their own `ApplicationDbContext` can I even refer in my other context to `ApplicationUser`? I write in MVC5 `UserProfile` is now `ApplicationUser`.